# join table, always return left table

Tags: sql, mysql

Here is my current query (dont mind about long select table)

```
SELECT user.id, 
 nawafil.date, nawafil.tahajjud, nawafil.rakaat_tahajjud, nawafil.witir, nawafil.qo_subuh, 
 nawafil.qo_dzuhur, nawafil.ba_dzuhur, nawafil.ba_maghrib, nawafil.ba_isya, 
 nawafil.dzikir_pagi, nawafil.dzikir_sore, nawafil.dzikir_malam, nawafil.quran, 
 nawafil.infaq, nawafil.dhuha, nawafil.dakwah, nawafil.ket_dakwah
 FROM nawafil
 JOIN user ON nawafil.id_user = user.id
 JOIN halaqah ON halaqah.id = user.halaqah_id
 WHERE user.halaqah_id = 1 AND nawafil.date = '2023-10-7'
```

i want to select all user table and nawafil that have same halaqah, in this case halaqah_id = 1 and specific date. But some user dont have nawafil with that specific date so they dont come in result.

Any idea to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just found the answer for my question.

I flip the `JOIN` and replace it with `LEFT JOIN`.

I also placed the date condition after the `LEFT JOIN`.

```
FROM user
LEFT JOIN nawafil
ON nawafil.id_user = user.id AND nawafil.date = '2023-10-6'
JOIN halaqah
ON halaqah.id = user.halaqah_id
WHERE user.halaqah_id = 1
```

Comment: Glad you found the answer. You should use proper date literals though: `nawafil.date = DATE '2023-10-06'`.